# Workbox cache is not used in offline

Tags: javascript, caching, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I'm totally new about workbox and service-worker.

With workbox, I cache every files (js, html, css, png, etc.). But I don't know why I get this error :

> GET https://my.site.com/js/patient.js net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

In the devtools > Cache storare, my patient.js is cached. Here a screenshot of the Cache Storage:
[image]

This is my service-worker:

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/6.1.5/workbox-sw.js');

workbox.core.skipWaiting();
workbox.core.clientsClaim();
workbox.precaching.cleanupOutdatedCaches();
  
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST, {
  ignoreURLParametersMatching: [/.*/],
});

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  console.debug("sw install");
  event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.debug("sw activated");
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});
```

But the weirdest thing is that the problem occurs (from what I've seen) only on patient.js. I don't have this problem on other JS.

How to resolve this problem. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Is patient.js included via a normal script element or some other loading mechanism?

Comment: @waxwing I include patient.js like this in my patient.html `<script src="js/patient.js"></script>`

Comment: Then I have no answer. I have had issues with the cache not matching when using alternative request methods (either due to a Chrome bug or different request headers). Have you checked the logs in the console? Workbox logs quite a bit in development mode.

Comment: Actually, it's random.... Now i have a GET https://my.site.com/js/xxxx.js net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED. It's not patient.js anymore. I don't know why ...

Comment: @kirusamma did you mange to fix this?

Comment: @NirBerko Sorry for my late reply. No I didn't manage to fix this. I removed Workbox and cached my files manually